# Incrementing my loops correctly

Tags: vba, excel

The code below calculate an average between col E, colG and col I (like in the picture in column K)but something doesn't work how I need. My code doesn't take correctly column G. It takes in the loop 5,7,3,15,10 and not 5,5,7,3,3,3,15,15,10,10. It doesn't consider how many repetitive names are in column A. How to solve the problem? Anyone is able to help? thanks!
(look at the picture)[image]

```
   For f= 1 To ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   nameF = ws.Range("F" & f).Value
     For totRng = 1 To lastrowA
       'if names from col A and col F coincide, then sum their numbers from col E
        If nameF = ws.Range("A" & totRng).Value Then ws.Range("G" & f).Value = 
        ws.Range("G" & f).Value + ws.Range("E" & totRng).Value

        On Error Resume Next
        If nameF = ws.Range("A" & totRng).Value Then _
            ws.Range("H" & f).Value = ((ws.Range("E" & f).Value / ws.Range("G" & f).Value)) * ws.Range("I" & f).Value

     Next totRng
   Next f
```

I should change this value: '/ ws.Range("G" & f).Value)'

Comment: Hi, first of all check you have spelled correctly all the variable names. In the first loop you declare that `f` is the counter but after this at the end you typed `Next FRowsNr` and the same in the second loop `totRng` is the counter and then you increment `totalRng`..

Comment: To avoid unintended declaration of variable I always use `Option Explicit` at the start of module.. Compiler will then tell you if there is any undeclared variables.. This will help you in the debuggin..

Comment: @ SickDimension: oh, yes. I didn't copy correctly.

Comment: @SickDimension: I put Option Explicit and now all variables are declared. But, do you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your column G is a sumup of column E. So what is the reason behind doubling sumup of column G?

Comment: @lowak : I need that column to calculate the average

Comment: Do you mean column G or E?

Comment: I mean column G. In the average I use column G as a divisor

Comment: One mistake atleast on line `ws.Range("H" & f).Value = ((ws.Range("E" & f).Value / ws.Range("G" & f).Value)) * ws.Range("I" & f).Value` i suppose should be `ws.Range("H" & f).Value = ((ws.Range("E" & totRng).Value / ws.Range("G" & f).Value)) * ws.Range("I" & totRng).Value`

Comment: And if I understand correctly, your problem is not having the value of col G incorrect but that you incremented the col E and I incorrectly and got wrong result in col H?

Comment: @SickDimension I tried your code too but the results in col H are not correct. In H2 I get 0 (instead of 3)and in H3 I get 2.85714285714286 (instead of 1,2)

Comment: SickDimension: no! Are correct the values from col E and I I get. I want to increment col E and I but I don't want to increment col G for each row (like col E and I). I should increment col G only if don't match to column A

Comment: Well, that's what I just tried to say.. I missed one thing on the code line `ws.Range("H" & f).Value = ws.Range("H" & f).Value + (((ws.Range("E" & totRng).Value / ws.Range("G" & f).Value)) * ws.Range("I" & totRng).Value)` now it should act just as your column K pseudos-- Oh my, just as I thought, forgive me not realizing befor e that you are actually incrementing the value of cell G while you are calculationg the average.. So your first loop the value of G = 3 and second loop value of G = 5 so you'll get result of ((3/3)*5) + ((2/5)*3) ..

Comment: still does not work properly. The values I get in H2=11 and H3=2.85714285714286. That values are not correct! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working piece of code

```
For f = 2 To ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
nameF = ws.Range("F" & f).Value
    For totRng = 2 To lastrowA
       'if names from col A and col F coincide, then sum their numbers from col E
        If nameF = ws.Range("A" & totRng).Value Then
            ws.Range("G" & f).Value = ws.Range("G" & f).Value + ws.Range("E" & totRng).Value
        End If
    Next totRng

    For totRng = 2 To lastrowA
        'calculate the average
        If nameF = ws.Range("A" & totRng).Value Then
            Debug.Print nameF & " found on line " & totRng & " person we have is on line " & f & ". Formula is : ((" & ws.Range("E" & totRng).Value & "/" & ws.Range("G" & f).Value & ")*" & ws.Range("I" & totRng).Value & "=" & (((ws.Range("E" & totRng).Value / ws.Range("G" & f).Value)) * ws.Range("I" & totRng).Value)
            ws.Range("H" & f).Value = ws.Range("H" & f).Value + (((ws.Range("E" & totRng).Value / ws.Range("G" & f).Value)) * ws.Range("I" & totRng).Value)
        End If
    Next totRng
Next f
```

Comment: Remember to empty the values on col H & G before running, or make empty the values from code..

Comment: Duh, and I forgot the header as well, made some adjustments.

Comment: still doesn't work correctly. The values I get are not correct.

Comment: yes. G2=5 and H2=4,2. But G3-Gn and H3-Hn are not correct

Comment: H3 should be: H3=((E3/G2)*I3) and NOT H3=((E3/G3)*I3)

Comment: Nope if you look at your own column K then H3 = ((E4/G3)*I4) = 2

Comment: exactly. sorry. You're right. But the value isn't correct in H3

Comment: I added a debugger line, run this code and show me what is printed to the immediate window...

Comment: Andrew found on line 2 person we have is on line 2
Andrew found on line 3 person we have is on line 2
Edward found on line 4 person we have is on line 3
Eric found on line 5 person we have is on line 4
Eric found on line 6 person we have is on line 4
Eric found on line 7 person we have is on line 4
Helen found on line 8 person we have is on line 5
...

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the increment action is working but now some of value on Edwards is not as it seems.. Check if the data on I4 and E4 is really 2 and an integer?

Comment: I refined the debug.print. Try running it again and show what the line "Edward" says on the immediate..

Comment: sorry for delay. Andrew found on line 2 person we have is on line 2. Formula is : ((3/5)*5=3
Andrew found on line 3 person we have is on line 2. Formula is : ((2/5)*3=1.2
Edward found on line 4 person we have is on line 3. Formula is : ((7/7)*2=2

Comment: OK, so there is absolutely nothing wrong with the code it seems.. Does the Edward line repeat somewhere in the immediate window? Is the Cell H3 correctly formatted? Is there another part of code that changes the value of cell H3?

Comment: No, doesn't repeat Edward line. It's only one line with Edward. No. H3=8 and should be 2  ((7/7)*2=2). No, anything else changes the value of H3

Comment: Did you remember to empty the columns G & H?

Comment: Now it's ok. I have to sum all partial values to get the average. Now works perfectly! Thanks very very much! You are a genius!